# How to sort a list of tuples by the length of the tuple

Tags: python

I have a list, which has a bunch of tuples of different sizes inside. Each Tuple contains a certain number of objects. I want to sort the list so the tuples with 1 object are all before tuples with 2 objects etc. I know tuples have a built in length but I dont know how to use it with the sort method in python. Thank you!

Comment: `your_list.sort(key=len)`. The `key` keyword argument takes a function that is applied to each element of `your_list`, sorting `your_list` by the result of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
print(sorted(list_of_tuples,key=len))
```

Or:

```
list_of_tuples.sort(key=len)
print(list_of_tuples)
```

Both reproduce the expected result.